# Do I need to pay if I collect my luggage and recheck?

Tags: luggage

My flight ticket Edinburgh to Tashkent from Turkish Airlines and baggage allowance is 40 kg for all the way (Edinburgh-Istanbul-Tashkent). But, I want to stay in Istanbul for a few days, so I am going to change the date of the trip Edinburgh-Istanbul. My luggage allowance won't be charged if I collect my luggage and recheck it?

Answer (score 6):

If you stay in Istanbul for a few days, you won't have a choice about collecting your luggage and rechecking: it will be mandatory. The airline will not hold your luggage for days.

Your luggage allowance will change to be whatever is allowed for Edinburgh-Istanbul and Istanbul-Tashkent separately. Turkish Airlines has a weirdly complex [free baggage policy](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/free-baggage/index.html), with [extra free baggage for frequent fliers](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-us/miles-and-smiles/program-details/index.html) and different amounts of baggage depending on fare, which is presumably how you wound up with a 40kg allowance. You would need to contact them to determine precisely what allowance you would have depending on your fare, as they do not publish a chart that shows all the exceptions.

If any [baggage charges](https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/excess-baggage/index.html) apply to your trip, you will need to pay the fees for both the trip from Edinburgh to Istabul and the trip from Istanbul to Tashkent, because several days in Istanbul will count as a stopover. The linked page has instructions for "Flights with a stopover" to calculate the total cost: find the fee for each portion of your journey and add them up. If you remain within your free baggage allowance, you will, of course, not be charged.

Comment: And a small note for the OP. That 40kg allowance doesn't mean 1 bag 40. Don't go above 28 or worse 32 per bag. People usually confuse such an allowance and over pack 1 bag because usually the allowance is much lesser

Comment: @HankyPanky I'm thinking to get two suitcase with 20kg each, thanks for your comment.

Comment: My ticket is bought by my company and in the ticket it says 40 kg luggage allowance not more than 28 kg each bag. As I know, I don't pay anything for 40kg baggage, but my worries is that I may need to pay if I collect in Istanbul and recheck them.

Comment: When you change the date you will get the new conditions on the new flight. They may or may not be same but it's only a matter of reading it on their website. You can also contact them and ask for a ticket on the new date with same allowance. Simple

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev Yes, it is possible that your allowance may change if you change your ticket. It may also stay the same. You'd have to contact them to find out, as it seems to depend on the specific fare involved.